# Search given word or word couples that not in a href tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# and default regex engine of .net core.

I need a regex pattern;

> Search given word (an ex: "stackoverflow" ) or word couples ( an ex: "stackoverflow sites" ) that not in a href tags / not hyperlinked.

An example:
Given word is "stackoverflow" ( Ignore char upper case, lower case. )

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a> is very useful site to learn what causes <b>stackoverflow</b> or not.
```

Another example;

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Good stackoverflow site</a> is actually very good site to learn what causes stackoverflow in software.
```

I need to catch first "stackoverflow" after the word of "causes" because other "Stackoverflow"(s) is hyperlinked.

What I've tried so far;

```
string regexPattern = $@"\b{wordCouple}(.*?)[^</a]\b";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match match = regex.Match(text);
```

But it's not working. How can I write this regex ?

**Update**: *More info upon request and commentors*;

I can't use html parser because of business rules;

I have an **ordered list** to hyperlink all word or word groups. I need to consider whole "body html" because of these rules.

Rules are;
- Only 1 word should be hyperlinked for 1 group's words.
- Max 3 words should be hyperlinked for all groups.
- Don't hyperlinked a word/word group if it's already hyperlinked.

So here is what I've tried;

```
    public class HyperlinkWordGroup
    {
        public HyperlinkWordGroup()
        {
            Words = new List();
        }

        /// 
        /// Hyperlink word group name.
        /// 
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        /// 
        /// "_self": Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default).
        /// or
        /// "_blank": Opens the linked document in a new window or tab.
        /// 
        public string UrlTarget { get; set; }

        public List Words { get; set; }
    }

private string ReplaceBodyAgility(string text, List group)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            const int maxHyperlinkedCount = 3;
            int count = 0;

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(text);

            List htmlNodes = doc.DocumentNode
                                          .Descendants()
                                          .ToList();

            foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in htmlNodes)
            {
                if (count == maxHyperlinkedCount)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (! htmlNode.Name.Equals("#text"))
                {
                    // Load next htmlNode because we want texts not tags.
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (HyperlinkWordGroup wordGroup in group)
                {
                    foreach (string wordCouple in wordGroup.Words)
                    {
                        string regexPattern = $@"\b{wordCouple}\b";
                        Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                        Match match = regex.Match(htmlNode.InnerHtml);

                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            string link = $" {wordCouple} ";

                            htmlNode.InnerHtml = htmlNode.InnerHtml.Replace(wordCouple, link, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                            count = count + 1;

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (count == maxHyperlinkedCount)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
```

Ofcourse this code fails because I need to consider order of "List group". If I run this function, all htmlagilitypack's "$text" comes respectively, but I should look at whole html body not line by line or not htmltag by htmltag.

So that's why I need to regex to find first word or word group which is not hyperlinked.

Comment: Please use an HTML parser to do this, not regex.

Comment: Ohhh... Good old [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) :) Maybe I should use it as duplicate... Please consider [edit] to clarify why you must use regex or what alternatives you are willing to consider.

Comment: It is best if you throw away all HTML stuff and dwell on plain text substitution. I think all you need is a kind of `Regex.Replace(text, 
$@"\b(?:{string.Join("|", wordGroup.Words.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))})\b", "<a href="https://some-site.com/">$&</a>")` without any `foreach`es.